# Passing 'Docker Run' Options to Mesos/Marathon/Chronos

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon, mesos-chronos

I am trying to run my containers in mesos and outputting all logs to Cloudwatch. According to Docker documentation, I should pass the following to 'docker run':

```
--log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=myLogGroup
```

(from https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/awslogs/#awslogs-region)

to docker run. In order to achieve this using Marathon (or Chronos, I assume?) , I should add the following block to my configuration json file for my task

```
            "parameters": [
            { "key": "hostname", "value": "a.corp.org" },
            { "key": "volumes-from", "value": "another-container" },
            { "key": "lxc-conf", "value": "..." }
        ]
```

https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html

It appears that this config appends the following to your docker run

```
--{key}={value}
```

Since I need to do something of the form "--log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1", I am putting "key": "log-opt awslogs-region", "value": "us-east-1", which generates the docker run command correctly, as I can see from stderr in mesos. However, I then get an error saying

```
unknown flag: --log-opt awslogs-region
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Running the generated docker run command from stderr directly on the mesos slave works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the args parameter to pass custom docker run options,

"args": [
    "--log-driver",
    "awslogs"
  ]